# How can I verify my selfsigned certificate when using easywebdav?

Tags: python, ssl, webdav, owncloud

I know [how to connect to my owncloud with python, by using easywebdav](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22555296/383793).

I'm using a selfsigned certificate and `verify_ssl=False`, but that makes me vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, the only reason to use ssl in the first place.

I'm using Fedora and tried adding my servers certificate to `$HOME/.pki/CA/cacert.pem`, but it still fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have your server certificate in `$HOME/.pki/CA/cacert.pem`. But to be complete for others, you can get a certificate with python like this:

```
import ssl
import os
# get the https certificate
cert = ssl.get_server_certificate(('example.com', 443))
# append it to my personal chain
pem_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.pki/CA/cacert.pem')
with open(pem_path, 'a+') as f:
    f.write(cert)
```

Then to use it in easywebdav. [Easywebdav builds on requests](https://github.com/amnong/easywebdav/blob/32842b13a67b1bda78f8687f6db543d0497bc5b6/easywebdav/client.py#L2). And the `verify_ssl` is used as `requests.Session.verify` [Requests docs say](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) it accepts a boolean *(True uses the default chain)* or a **path to a CA_BUNDLE**.

So this should work:

```
import easywebdav
pem_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.pki/CA/cacert.pem')
webdav = easywebdav.connect('example.com', username='user', password='pass', 
                            protocol='https', port=443,
                            verify_ssl=pem_path)
...
```